# Python paired dictionary keys()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Well, I have this dictionary in this form:

```
{'Komp': ['values'], 'Forx': ['values'], 'Rove': ['values']}
```

And I want to make tuples of all the possible key pairs, something like this:

```
[('Komp','Forx'), ('Komp','Rove'), ('Forx', 'Rove')]
```

maybe even in a list as in the example, I don't care about the order in this case. I am quite new at this so I am quite grateful for help.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708253/making-combinations-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) can come in handy

```
d = {'Komp': ['values'], 'Forx': ['values'], 'Rove': ['values']}
from itertools import combinations
for x in combinations(d, 2):
   print x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (using [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 2))
```